# Unable to download financial statements using yfinance module

Tags: python-3.x, yfinance

I am trying to download financial statements using yfinance 0.1.74 version
However, all it is returning is an empty dataframe
I tried upgrading my yfinance module , different financial statements
Also, tried different tickers but to no avail

This is the code I tried and the output below it

[MSFT ticker using yfinance module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EgaM.png)

[Cashflow statements code & output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsYZf.png)

I was expecting it to return the cashflow statement.
Can someone help me with this ?